# How to notify the application UI thread from Sync Adapters?

Tags: android, process, android-room, android-syncadapter

**Background:**

I am using **Sync Adapters** to upload media file on the cloud.

Media metadata like isSynced, mediaPath etc. are stored in sqlite database.
I am not using `Content Provider` to manage or access the data from sqlite database.

My application is able to sync data in background or when the application is closed.

On one of the screen, within my application I am showing syncing of the media. I am showing the counter as **Current media being sync / total media count**.

Each media takes **approximately 2 to 3 seconds** to sync withe cloud.

**Problem:**

How to notify the UI/Screen from another process very frequently. There are 200 media and all are being uploaded sequentially. I need to show the updated counter of how many files are pending for sync on the UI.

I am also planning to replace `SQLiteOpenHelper` with `Room Persistence Library`.

**Expected:**

1. How to notify the UI of the updated media remaining for sync, already synced across different process(because of Sync Adapters)?
2. If I replace `SQLiteOpenHelper` with `Room Persistence Library` then how to get instance of the same?

**An optimised, code or way to update the UI very frequently.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried posting events with the help of Bus (library)? Or maybe Broadcast Receiver? i think that's the way to go.

Comment: Yes, the Broadcast Receiver helped somewhat across the process.